# How can I change a prop on a React Element saved in an Array? JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im creating this custon React Element and pushing it into an array.

```
let new_image = <KonvaImage 
                            ref={newImageRef}
                            key={this.state.itemArray.length}
                            image={image}
                            width={new_size.width * reduction}
                            height={new_size.height * reduction}
                            x={ (width / 2 ) - (new_size.width * reduction / 2)}
                            y={ (height / 2) - (new_size.height * reduction / 2)}
                            draggable
                        />

        this.state.itemArray.push(new_image)
```

But I want to make the prop "draggable" conditional, depending on one state variable from his parent.

But it seems that i can't because this react element is read-only when it's created on the code above.

I want to change the prop on render, here:

```
render(){
        return( 
                 { //Renders all items into the canvas
                   this.state.itemArray.map(item => (
                      item   
                   ))
                            
                 }
        )
}
```

I have no clue on what to do, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use React.cloneElement

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```js
React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

You should be able to do this:

```js
this.state.itemArray.push(React.cloneElement(
  new_image,
  { draggable: whatever_you_want }
))
```

If you prefer to do this to the whole array later, and if your set of components is a *genuine* Array, you can use traditional array addressing and manipulation to modify one or more items by replacing the initial components with clones whose properties have been modified. Otherwise, you'll need `React.Children` to work with a collection of children.

Comment: Thanks! this works great, and solves my problem about the modified propierties too!!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider pushing a *higher-order component* to the array and then providing the prop when you render it.

You would add it like this:

```
let new_image = ({ draggable }) => (
  <KonvaImage
    ref={newImageRef}
    key={this.state.itemArray.length}
    image={image}
    width={new_size.width * reduction}
    height={new_size.height * reduction}
    x={width / 2 - (new_size.width * reduction) / 2}
    y={height / 2 - (new_size.height * reduction) / 2}
    draggable={draggable}
  />
);

this.state.itemArray.push(new_image)
```

And then when iterating through the array:

```
render(){
  return this.state.itemArray.map((Item) => <Item draggable={false} />);
};
```

Comment: It works but when the properties change, the element updates and returns to the original props, I think the answer from Tom above works better in my case. Thank You tho! I didn't know what you showed was possible